# Installing SharePoint Foundation 2013 Prerequisites on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, windows-server-2012-r2, prerequisites, app-fabric

I am trying to install SP 2013 Foundation Prerequisites on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard environment. Unforunately, I am not even able to get past the prerequisites. First, it was throwing an error related to Sync Framework v1 runtime and so I installed this manually. Then, when I ran the prerequisite installer again, I keep getting error for AppFabric 1.1, saying it is not able to install this. The interesting thing is that, it already has AppFabric 1.1 installed, although not all the features of AppFabric like Caching Services and Cache Administration are installed (rest of them are installed). When I try to manually enable these features, it doesn't let me. So, I am stuck now. Can anyone please help me?

I tried out many things like removing the environment variable for AppFabric, following the powershell approach for installing the prereqs and so on, but no luck.

Comment: Please try to install prerequisites from installer and trace the errors provided in log file. Also you can put those errors here in question so one can easily understand and provide you feedback.

Comment: I have got some pointers when I posted it in msdn forum. Here is the link. But I am still facing issues.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c64b9948-91cb-44ac-8a41-18868d3342f5/installing-sharepoint-foundation-2013-prerequisites-on-windows-server-2012-r2-standard?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this along with the details can be found at

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c64b9948-91cb-44ac-8a41-18868d3342f5/installing-sharepoint-foundation-2013-prerequisites-on-windows-server-2012-r2-standard?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as OP. Spent days trying to find a fix. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling AppFabric via command line. It did not work for me. I then tried the PSModulePath solution that's been suggested everywhere. Did not work for me. At one point I realised I couldn't even install AppFabric at all (error code 1603) so I couldn't uninstall it either which is why a lot of the fixes weren't working. I must have stuffed something up from one of the fixes I found online.

I don't know if that was your issue, but ultimately I started the installation from scratch again. It was faster. I still ran into the App Fabric issue but I followed Mohamed's solution above where I installed AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe (manually double clicking) right after installing WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe via command line. It fking worked. I hope this can help someone. I spent way too long beating a dead horse with the original install that I probably stuffed up.